# Creating a New Dataframe based off a SumIf Calculation in Another Datafram Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, countif

My Current Dataframe looks like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'num_specimen_seen': [10, 2, 1, 8]},
                  index=['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish'])
df
        num_legs  num_wings  num_specimen_seen
falcon         2          2                 10
dog            4          0                  2
spider         8          0                  1
fish           0          0                  8
```

How can I now create a new dataframe that is a sumif calculation on the above columns. So far I have the below:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['CountIfWings'] = (df.num_wings == '2').sum()
```

But that does not work, however when I just assign it to a variable i am able to see the value:

```
variable1 = (df.num_wings == '2').sum()
print(variable1)
1
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use `DataFrame` constructor, because output is scalar:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'CountIfWings':[(df.num_wings == '2').sum()]})
#if 2 are integers
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'CountIfWings':[(df.num_wings == 2).sum()]})
```

Comment: I tried the above but now getting the following error: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: @Yusuf Cattaneo Do you forget for `[]`?